# Dynamic search in files

Tags: excel, vba, iteration

I am building a small search with xl files.
I have an xl sheet with column A, and I want to iterate through each cell in this col, and then to grab this value.

Then iterate through all files in a folder that I defined to look in (and it's subfolders) and look for matching values in a specific column (A for example) in each file. when it match, it adds it to another sheet with all the results.

So I managed to iterate through all the files in the folder and subfolders, and look for a specific value that I defined.

THE PROBLEM is when I got to the dynamic part - when I run through all the values in the column of the source file, and not just for a specific value.

I post my code with the comments and also where I think the problem is...

```
Sub SearchFolders()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim wOut As Worksheet
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim strFirstAddress As String
    Dim oFolder, oSubfolder, oFile, queue As Collection
    Dim HostFolder As String

    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
    StartTime = Timer

    '********************
    'GET FIRST COL VALUES
    '********************
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim searchItem As Variant
    strSearch = ""
    For i = 1 To Rows.Count
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
           strSearch = strSearch & "," & Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next i
    'MsgBox (strSearch)
    searchItem = Split(strSearch, ",")

    HostFolder = "C:\Users\a\Desktop\xl files min\temp"

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False



    Set wOut = Worksheets.Add
    lRow = 1
    With wOut
        .Cells(lRow, 1) = "Workbook"
        .Cells(lRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
        .Cells(lRow, 3) = "Cell"
        .Cells(lRow, 4) = "Text in Cell"

        'now some iterations through subfolders and folders
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set queue = New Collection
        queue.Add fso.GetFolder(HostFolder)

        Do While queue.Count > 0
            Set oFolder = queue(1)
            queue.Remove 1 'dequeue

            For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
                queue.Add oSubfolder 'enqueue
            Next oSubfolder
            strFile = Dir(oFolder & "\*.xls*")
            Do While strFile <> ""
                Set wbk = Workbooks.Open _
                      (Filename:=oFolder & "\" & strFile, _
                      UpdateLinks:=0, _
                      ReadOnly:=True, _
                      AddToMRU:=False)

                For Each wks In wbk.Worksheets
                    For j = 1 To UBound(searchItem) 'start iterating through the column's values
                        strSearch = searchItem(j) '***********A PROBLAM IN HERE?:
                        '******************************IF I PUT THE ARRAY LIKE SO AND MATCH, IT GOT STUCK, THOUGH,
                        'IF I PUT THE A VALUE THAT I KNOW THAT MATCH AS STRING FOR EXAMPLE
                        'I CAN DO: strSearch =  "bla" THEN IT DOES WORKS... BUT I NEED THE DYNAMIC COL VALUES :\
                        '******************************************************
                        'MAYBE HERE THE PROBLAM? IF THERE IS A MATCH IT GOT STUCK
                            Set rFound = wks.UsedRange.Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) 'HERE
                            'MsgBox (strSearch)
                            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                                strFirstAddress = rFound.Address
                            End If
                            Do
                                If rFound Is Nothing Then
                                    Exit Do
                                Else
                                    lRow = lRow + 1
                                    .Cells(lRow, 1) = oFolder & "\" & strFile
                                    .Cells(lRow, 2) = wks.Name
                                    .Cells(lRow, 3) = rFound.Address & temp
                                    .Cells(lRow, 4) = rFound.Value
                                End If
                                Set rFound = wks.Cells.FindNext(After:=rFound)
                            Loop While strFirstAddress <> rFound.Address
                        'End If
                    Next j
                Next

                wbk.Close (False)

            strFile = Dir
            Loop
        Loop


        .Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
    MsgBox ("This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds -- " & j)

ExitHandler:
    Set wOut = Nothing
    Set wks = Nothing
    Set wbk = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oSubfolder = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set queue = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler

End Sub
```

Comment: What error do you get when you run this code?

Comment: I don't get any error it just keep on running until I hit ctrl + alt + del.
though I did some tests and I got weird results, when I open the file and do a first run it works good, AT FIRST TIME, but, then when I edit the source col, the dynamic col,and run the code again, then it got stuck...

Comment: could you try and replace the `wks.Cells.FindNext` in you innermost while loop with `wks.UsedRange.FindNext`?

Comment: same results... :\
it is very weird. when I stop the program with ctrl + al +del, it shows the run time msgBox that i did, and it shows small time run, it looks like something after it dont work...
I would realy appreciate if you will try the code by yourself, I never encountered problam like this...

Comment: At the begginng, when you define your variables, Dim x,y,z as Integer, doesn't make x and y an integer, only z. So when you define your collections you need to put `Dim oFolder As Collection, oSubfolder As Collection, oFile As Collection, queue As Collection`, can you put `Exit Sub` before your `ExitHandler`?! If an Error would occur there, then this would jump to `ErrHandler`, where it would display the MsgBox, but Visualupdating is off....

Comment: Also, i think your search array will start at 0